# Hide Navigation Item but show Back Bar Button

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Now, I will put an image at the top of the screen in the design I created. However, the Navigation Title area is displaying the image in white color. Since I need the back button, I want to move the white color from the Navigation Title to below it. But I still want to keep the back button. How can I easily do this? Please assist me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdcP6.png)

self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: false)

I tried this actions but this solutions navigation Item disappear on my screen back button also hidden. I don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

First make a custom back button in storyboard.

Hide the navigation bar in viewDidLoad()

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

And use this line of code.

```
    @IBAction func customBackButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Am sure it will help you. Thank you.

Comment: No this is not helpful and don't useful. Because this hidden all area. But I want a back bar button. I want to delete only white area.

Comment: Please provide your code how you are implementing. In my case there is no white area by default. Because navigation bar is transparent, not white.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but since you talk about a back button we can assume that the view controller with the picture has been pushed on a navigation controller. The navigation bar in your image looks very non-standard and doesn’t extend to the top of the screen. But your question has tags that imply you are using the standard navigation controller and bar classes.

You can customise the appearance of the navigation bar when your picture view controller is top-most in the stack:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()

    navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
    navigationItem.compactAppearance = appearance
    navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

Comment: Hey Geoff I'm sorry about not clear question. When you saw picture I shared. I don't want to white area. My imageView on the white area and only show a bar back button. Not white area. This white area destroy my pictures. Thank you.

Comment: If my solution does not work then you need to provide more information on your view hierarchy and how you set up the navigation bar. You must be doing something to make it look different to the default.

Comment: If you have any other advice other than this, I'll take it. In short, what I want is to keep that back button and leave that other white area. Frankly, I couldn't quite understand whether I should mention the View hierarchy for this.